# Why is order of bits not getting reversed?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, hdl

In this code, while declaring `in` and `out`, the seventh bit of input is MSB, while the zeroth bit of output is MSB. So, why is the Verilog compiler keeping the order same in the output?  PFA simulated waveform in edaplayground.

```
//code of Design module

module design1(in,out);
  input  [7:0]in;
  output [0:7]out;
  assign out=in;
endmodule


//Testbench

module design1_tb();
 reg [7:0]in;
 wire [0:7]out;
 design1 uut(in,out);
 initial begin
   in=8'b00010101;
 end
 initial begin
   //Dump waves
   $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
   $dumpvars(1);
 end
endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The order looks the same due to how the waveform viewer displays the 2 signals.  For `in`, `in[0]` is the rightmost value in the display (`1`).  For `out`, `out[7]` is the rightmost.

```
  assign out=in;
```

is the same as

```
  assign out[0:7]=in[7:0];
```

which is the same as:

```
  assign out[0]=in[7];
  assign out[1]=in[6];
  assign out[2]=in[5];
  assign out[3]=in[4];
  assign out[4]=in[3];
  assign out[5]=in[2];
  assign out[6]=in[1];
  assign out[7]=in[0];
```

If you can stick to the more conventional range declaration (`[7:0]`), you might be less confused.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog always aligns *left* to *right* index in `[left:right]` where it right-justifies the `right` index as the least-significant bit(LSB). It doesn't care about the endianness (whether 0 is the LSB or MSB) or if you want to start numbering bits at some other value than 0.

If you want to reverse the bit ordering so the the LSB becomes the MSB, you will need to use a `for` loop

```
module design1(
  input  [7:0]in,
  output [0:7]out);
  genvar i;
  for (i=0;i<8;i=i+1)
     assign out[i] = in[i];
endmodule
```

or in SystemVerilog you could use the streaming operator

```
module design1(
  input  [7:0]in,
  output [0:7]out);
  assign out = {<<{in}};
endmodule
```